# Convert data frame back to rules (arules package)

Tags: r, dataframe, arules, market-basket-analysis

I am using the `apriori` function of the `arules` R package to generate association rules. Because of the large number of possible rules, I have to run the function several times with different `minlen` and `maxlen` parameters each time, otherwise I would always get `Error: cannot allocate vector of size n GB`.

My intention is to use the function `as(rules, "data.frame")` to convert the rules into several data frames and then concatenate those data frames into one and convert it back to rules.

Do you think my solution would work? If so, which function should I use to convert the data frame back to rules to inspect it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create data frames. If you have several rules objects then you can combine them with `c()`. For example

```
rules <- c(r1, r2, r3)
```

See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-2/topics/combine